# How to export UTF-8 .txt file from SSIS to Azure Blob Destination?

Tags: sql, azure, ssis

I currently have this data flow task wherein I have a flat-file (.CSV) as source which I need to aggregate some of the columns in and export the UTF-8 .txt file to an Azure Blob Storage.

However, the fields for Azure Blob Destination only contains setting for the Blob name without any fields for the file format nor the encoding of the said format.

May I know how such file can be exported into a Blob storage with a format of .TXT and an encoding of UTF-8?

I have already tried changing the Code Page from the "General" tab of the Flat File Source Manager but it returns an error.

Upon checking the exported file in the Azure Blob Storage, the file is encoded in ANSI format.

Comment: Is that you want to know how to upload txt file as UTF-8 to Azure blob storage?